# How to find which model is selected by TPOT

Tags: python, tpot

Hi am using TPOT for machine learning I am getting 99% accuracy but I am not sure to which model did it predict can someone help me with this also does it do SMOTE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you stored the TPOTClassifier in the variable my_tpot, then you can access the final trained pipeline by accessing the   fitted_pipeline_ attribute:

```
my_tpot = TPOTClassifier()
my_tpot.fit(…)
print(my_tpot.fitted_pipeline_)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer I still have a doubt if TPOT can deal with imbalanced dataset and do SMOTE coz my data is highly imbalanced.....?